# How to find the moment generating function of a poisson translation.

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I want to find the mgf of $Y$, where $Y = ((X − λ)/√λ)$ and $X$ ~ Poisson$(λ)$. What steps should I take in order to arrive to the mgf of $Y$?

Comment: You need to know the definition of mgf, and how to compute the mgf of Poisson.

Answer (score 0):

The mgf of $X \sim$  Poisson($\lambda$) is:

$$
E[e^{tX}] = m_X(t) = \exp (\lambda (e^t -1))
$$

For the transformation, $Y = \frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$, we have:

$$
E[e^{tY}] = E[e^{t\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} }] = e^{-t\sqrt{\lambda}} E[e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}} X }] = e^{-t\sqrt{\lambda}} m_X(t/\sqrt{\lambda}) = e^{-t\sqrt{\lambda}} \exp (\lambda (e^\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}} -1))
$$